# Remove Duplicate data In Localstorage

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage, phonegap

I am facing difficulty in deleting duplicate data from `localStorage`, the platform use JavaScript on Cordova-Phone Gap, how can I delete duplicate data on localStorage ?

For example remove duplicate by ID **:**

```
[{ID=1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID=1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID=2, NAME:"HENRY"},
{ID=3, NAME:"JOHN"},
{ID=3, NAME:"JAMES"}]
```

**Expect :**

```
[{ID=1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID=2, NAME:"HENRY"},
{ID=3, NAME:"JOHN"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, where you wish to remove any objects with the **same *numerical* `ID`**, you can use a for-each loop to transfer the object stored in each element to the element index of an empty array *only if an object has not already been sent to the index **that shares its `ID`***

in your case, since you have no `ID:0`, the first element of the no-duplicate array will be undefined (and should be removed by `filter`ing).

Here is a working example (I replaced `=` with `:` in your objects). This will keep *only the first object of each ID*

```js
let data = [
{ID:1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID:1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID:2, NAME:"HENRY"},
{ID:3, NAME:"JOHN"},
{ID:3, NAME:"JAMES"}
];

const nonDuplicatedData = [];

data.forEach(x => {
if (!nonDuplicatedData[x.ID]) nonDuplicatedData[x.ID] = x;
});

const filteredData = nonDuplicatedData.filter(n => {return n != undefined});

console.log(filteredData);
```

If, instead of the first object for a given ID you want the last, simply remove `if (!nonDuplicatedData[x.ID])` from the `forEach` loop to keep replacing the object, leaving the final occurence for that ID number.

```js
let data = [
{ID:1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID:1, NAME:"JAMES"},
{ID:2, NAME:"HENRY"},
{ID:3, NAME:"JOHN"},
{ID:3, NAME:"JAMES"}
];

const nonDuplicatedData = [];

data.forEach(x => {
nonDuplicatedData[x.ID] = x;
});

const filteredData = nonDuplicatedData.filter(n => {return n != undefined});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Obviously, your `localStorage` version will have to be retrieved, `JSON.parse`d into an object and assigned to a variable (`data` here). After filtering, you'd have to `JSON.stringify` it before putting it back to `localStorage`. Also, this requires numeric IDs, it is not a general solution.